# How to extract content in between tags in Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file of ~500k lines with fairly random HTML syntax. The rough structure of the file is as follows:

```
content <title> title1 </title> more words 

title contents2 title more words <body> <title> title2 </title> 

<body><title>title3</title></body>
```

I want to extract all contents in between the  tags.

```
title1
title2 
title3
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    content_list = []

with open('C://Users//HOME//Desktop//Document_S//corpus_test//00.txt', errors = 'ignore') as openfile2:
    for line in openfile2:
        for item in line.split("<title>"):
            if "</title>" in item:
                content = (item [ item.find("<title>")+len("<title>") : ])
                content_list.append(content)
```

But this method is not retrieving all tags. I think this could be due to the tags that are connected to other words, without spaces. Ie. `<body><title>`.

I've considered replacing every '<' and '>' with a space and performing the same method, but if I was to do this, I would get "contents2" as an output.

Comment: Look into HTML parsers like `beautifulsoup`

Comment: I have tried, but I cannot find any patterns in the HTML for me to loop thru and extract all titles. If I simply print(soup.title) I get 'None' as output.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do this with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('file_to_read.txt', 'r'), 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('title'))
# [<title> title1 </title>, <title> title2 </title>, <title>title3</title>]

print(soup.find_all('title')[0].text)
# ' title1 '
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with your code syntax :

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for item in line.split('<title>'):
            if '</title>' in item:
                content_list.append(str.strip(item.split('</title>')[0]))
print(content_list)
```

But [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is for me the best alternative anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('C://Users//HOME//Desktop//Document_S//corpus_test//00.txt', 'r'), 'html.parser')
content_list = []
contents = soup.find_all('title')
for content in content:
    print(content.get_text().strip())
    content_list.append(content.get_text().strip())
```